# A better way to solve this question on Parabola?

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

Q: Let $P$ be a point on Parabola $y^2= 4x$ and $Q$ be a point on the line $L_1:  2x+y+4=0$.
If the line $L: x-y+1=0$ is the perpendicular bisector of $PQ$ ; then the coordinates of $P$ can be ?

My approach : 
The line $PQ$ is of form $x+y=c$ , and let $P(t²,2t)$. Since $P$ lies on the line we get $c$ in terms of $t$. Now since the lines $L$ and $PQ$ intersect at midpoint of $P$ and $Q$, I got the coordinates of midpoint and hence got $Q$ in terms of $t$. Then since $Q$ lies on the line $L_1$ I got an equation in $t$ which gives two values of $t$. And hence I got the $2$ coordinates of where $P$ can be....$(1,-2)$ and $(9,-6)$

As you may see this method is too cumbersome and I feel I am missing the point of the question..So is there a better way to do it ??

Comment: "line $PQ$ is of the form $x+y=c$" - this is not right. This makes $PQ$ parallel to $L$ but $L$ is perpendicualr to $PQ$.

Comment: @user160738 I have made the necessary corrections.

Comment: IMHO The method is not cumbersome. You are simply too lazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider L as a line of reflection and find out the equation of $L_2$ (the mirror image of $L_1$).
Then find out P (the intersection point of $L_2$ and the parabola).

Hint: $x+2y+3=0$ ($L_2$)

Comment: Works fine and fast.. Just one question how did you reflect the line ? I assumed two points on the line and reflected them to get the equation..Is there another way ?

Comment: @Sudhanshu I've used the same idea you had, but I used the intersection point of $L$ and $L_1$ and the $x$-intercept  of $L1$. The advantage is that the mirror image of the intersection point is itself.